# Mortgage requirements in the US for non-residents

Tags: united-states, investing, non-resident, mortgage-qualification

What are the conditions for an alien/non-resident American to obtain a home loan?

Say someone has worked in the US for a while, obtained an SSN and left the country for another one. They built assets in other countries and would like to purchase a home in the US. What conditions will such a person need to satisfy to get a home loan and how different would it be to obtaining a loan while you are a resident in the USA?

Answer (score 3):

Most common mortgage loans are written for homes that are the primary residence of the buyer. As a non-resident, you would be subject to stricter lending standards as would the buyer of a vacation property. The other tricky item is that you may have a social security number, but your credit report may not have enough history if you have not been using credit reported by the credit agencies in the US.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Updated tag. Does the importance of credit history depend on the usage of credit ? I would have thought if someone left the US with a good credit score, came back after a few year - would still be able to use the credit score. Which banking institutes could be approached for investing in property, from Australia ?